# headless libreoffice convert with border size

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Lately I have been playing around with libreoffice and the available conversion features.
For example I can convert with:
`libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf /tmp/test.html --outdir /tmp`

What I have noticed is that the borders are standard borders size. Is it possible to specify the border height or width.

Anybody came across a way to do that via command line or configuration file?

Thanks